# Bidirectional collection in java

Tags: java, collections

I have Many-to-Many associated entities information with me.

I would like to show the user the list of "students" and if user chooses an student, show his teachers.

Conversely, user may opt to see list of teachers and he/she can select a teacher to see all the students that teacher is teaching.

I am looking to have a java collection class (java built in or 3rd party) to represent such data so that I can query for teachers based on student or vice versa.

Bidi map comes quite close but it enforces 1:1 relationship. I have many to many relationship.

Any clues?

Answer (score 2):

i think you couldn't do that with a map. the most simple way would be, to create a Student class and a Teacher class. both of it could have a method like addTeacher(Teacher teacher) / addStudent(Student student). So each Student objects knows it Teachers and each Teacher object knows it Student.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for, but you can have a look at [Guava BiMap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html)

Comment: BiMap is same as BidiMap... It provides 1:1 association.

Comment: I see, have you considered trying composition of objects.. such as `Teacher` contains `List<Student>` and `Student` contains `List<Teacher>` as the object model.

Answer (score 1):

Does this not suffice?

```
Map<Student, Set<Teacher>> studentsToTeachers;
Map<Teacher, Set<Student>> teachersToStudents;
```

It's not a single collection, but it would solve your problem, provided your implementation was correct.

Comment: True... It would suffice and this is what I have done currently. But.. It means, now, I have 2 collections and... worse.. the information is repeating.. studentsToTeachers will have info about teachers as well as in teachersToStudents.